# Seekbar in recyclerview also moves recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, seekbar

Basically i have implemented recyclerview in nested scroll view which contains the arc seek bar in each item of recyclerview. So when i move seekbar recyclerview is also scrolling.

I tried using nestedscrollview and focusableInTouchMode option but did not worked.

```
device_list.apply {
            device_list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@RoomActivity, 2)
            device_list.adapter = DeviceAdapter()
        }
```

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/device_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginSemiGlobal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginSemiGlobal"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

```
<com.marcinmoskala.arcseekbar.ArcSeekBar
            app:roundEdges="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
            app:progressBackgroundColor="@color/colorProgressBackground"
            app:progressBackgroundWidth="8dp"
            app:progressColor="@color/colorProgress"
            android:id="@+id/dimmer"
            app:progressWidth="8dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:thumb="@drawable/ic_progress_thumb"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I tried setting setNestedScrollview to ViewCompact and also used focus in touch mode but output was same.

Comment: can you share some screenshots

Comment: here is gif explaining https://giphy.com/gifs/dvONgAEF3nUoAQQMyJ/html5

Comment: @KaushikBurkule can you upload your code on github?

Comment: i cant upload the actual code but i made sample app for clarifying same issue https://github.com/kaushikburkule/sample_scroll_problem.git